# Elements with opacity < 1 not rendering in chrome when not in first column

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, opacity

I have a site that gets divided into multiple columns. Whenever an element is not in the first column and has opacity set to < 1, it doesn't get rendered when its container has both the overflow y and border radius properties.

[Shown in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnyj3mtc/2/)

css

```
.main {
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
    column-width: 100px;
    max-height: 200px;
}

.main > div {
    overflow-y:auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.opac {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

html

```
<div class="main">
    <div>
        <div class="opac">element 1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="opac">element 2</div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div>
        <div class="opac">element 30</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using chrome 40.0.2214.94 (64-bit) on OSX 10.10.1. Works in Firefox.

Comment: That's crazy. Sounds like you should report it as a bug.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a rendering bug. I reproduced it in Canary 42.0.2291.0 on OSX. You should check for known issues and if necessary raise it on crbug.com

Comment: alright, submitted here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=column-width%20opacity&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=453933

Comment: Same result: Version 40.0.2214.93 m - Chrome Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [issue in chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=453933) doesn't seem like it will be fixed anytime soon and the `will-change: opacity` fix doesn't allow pointer/click events, I've decided to just calculate what the rgb values would be with the desired opacity and hard code them in CSS.

I was using the opacity for disabled buttons and was only using a few of the bootstrap button types for this particular case, so it's not too bad of a hack.

```
.btn.btn-success[disabled] {
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgb(141, 194, 141);
}
.btn.btn-info[disabled] {
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgb(120, 187, 206);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a rendering bug. For now you can mitigate the effect by applying `will-change: opacity` to the parent elements:

```
.main > div {
    overflow-y:auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    will-change: opacity;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yx1cp9f8/

Comment: yup, that fixed it. Never knew of that property so thanks! I've submitted a bug report so hopefully wont need the fix in the future.

Comment: Although, hover stylings still don't seem to work unless you reduce the browser window width and then expand it again. Like <a> tags don't show the pointer cursor or underline itself (http://jsfiddle.net/tnyj3mtc/3/). But at least they show up.

Comment: That's really interesting. Great spot!

Answer (score 1):

Anther workaround apparently is to set the opacity on the parent element:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="opac">
    <div >element 1</div>
</div>
<div class="opac">
    <div >element 2</div>
</div>
...
<div class="opac">
    <div >element 30</div>
</div>
```

Seems to work. (you seem to have forgotten to close your divs, so I did that as well)

Comment: I suspect anything that causes the parent element to be promoted to its own layer will do it.

Comment: oops, yah forgot to close them when copying from jsfiddle. Fixed now. styling the parent div isn't possible for me since the actual site is a bit more complicated.